# How does one define self in a python Class that already has self defined?

Tags: python, class, self

I just got back into python, and wanted to experiment with classes, when I run this code and want to add a word, this error shows up.

```
What would you like to do(add)
Word please(banana)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/gabrieltozman/Documents/word list.py", line 58, in <module>
    choice.addword()
  File "/Users/gabrieltozman/Documents/word list.py", line 20, in addword
    words.append(choice)
NameError: name 'words' is not defined
```

This might be a dumb mistake on my part, but help is apreciated.:)

```
import random
import csv
running=True
count=0
Die=csv.register_dialect('Die',delimiter=',',quotechar='|',quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
class Wordlist:
    words=[]
    def __init__(self,words,count,choice):
        self.words=words
        self.count=count
        self.choice=choice
    def shuffle(words):
        random.shuffle(words)
        return(words)
    def werdcount(words):
        for i in words:
            i=i+1
        return (count)
    def addword(choice):
        words.append(choice)
        return
    def removeword(choice):
        for i in words:
            if self.words[i] == choice:
                self.words.remove(words[i])
            i=i+1
        return
    def importlist(choice):
        with open('/Users/____/Desktop/wordlist.csv','r',newline='')as csvfile:
            reading=csv.reader(csvfile,dialect=Die)
        i=0
        for row in reader:
            self.words.append(row[i])
            i=i+1
        return (words)
    def exportlist(words):
        with open('/Users/____/Desktop/wordlist.csv','r',newline='')as csvfile, open('/Users/____/Desktop/wordlist.csv','w',newline='')as csvfile2:
            reading=csv.reader(csvfile,Die)
            writing=csv.writer(csvfile2,Die)
        i=0
        x=0
        for row in reading:
            i=i+1
        for row in row[i]:
            writing.writerows(self.words[x])
            x=x+1
            i=i+1
        return

while running:
    action=input("What would you like to do")
    if action == "STOP":
        running=False
    if action == "shuffle":
        words=shuffle(words)
    if action == "add":
        choice=Wordlist(None,None,(input("Word please")))
        choice.addword()
        print(words)
    if action == "export":
        words.exportlist()
```

This code is incomplete, but I'm just debugging it right now, and I've tried many things to fix it, but none of them seemed to fix it. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: You need to read up on the basics of python class definitions. This is all wrong

Comment: Test things as soon as you have made them. There are mistakes everywhere, not just related to classes. Please read about `for` loops. They are used precisely to avoid things like `i=i+1`... You also have many unneeded `return`. I would suggest creating and testing standalone functions before thinking about putting them in a class.

Answer (score 1):

When writing a class method, it's important to always include `self` as a parameter, so that Python knows who you are talking about.

```
def shuffle(self, words):
    random.shuffle(words)
    return(words)
```

This allows you to create a WordList and call `shuffle`:

```
w = WordList(...)
w.shuffle(...)
```

This is really just syntactic sugar, however, since it's really doing:

```
w = WordList(...)
WordList.shuffle(w, ...)
```

Comment: Thank you, this explained a lot. Greatly appreciated.